# Apache Redirect Not Working Correctly

Tags: apache

I have this in my apache .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificatekeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
Redirect 301 /recalls/recalls.html https://recallpatrol.com/recalls.html
</VirtualHost>
```

But no redirect is happening. I'm trying to prevent anyone hitting the `recalls` directly, which doesn't actually exist. I can't figure out where it's coming from, so in the meantime, I need a redirect.

Comment: Why do you have the same VirtualHost twice? Maybe I would start with merging them into one. The second VirtualHost doesn't have any server name, so I don't know how would Apache match it. Redirect itself looks good.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy That did the trick. Having the double Virtual Hosts was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I have added it as an answer so it may help others better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache matches a corresponding virtual host using the `ServerName`, but your second virtual host definition doesn't contain any, so Apache never matches that virtual host and thus ignores it completely.

So if both virtual hosts are for the same domain, just **merge them into one**:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificatekeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

    Redirect 301 /recalls/recalls.html https://recallpatrol.com/recalls.html
</VirtualHost>
```